# Mysql: rows having minimum value and prioritize where condition based on case

Tags: mysql, join, having

I have two tables, first table is:
`docs` 
and another table: 
`doc_val`

with `doc_id` as foreign key from table `docs`

I need to get list of `docs` (including `val`, `type` and `criteria` from `doc_val` ) which matches certain conditions, say for example: `doc_val.criteria = 'L' and docs.rev = 1`

While getting this list of docs I also need to make sure that the `doc_val.val` for given `doc_id` is the minimum. AND also make sure that `doc_val.type = 'D'`, given that the there exists `doc_val.type = 'D'` ELSE we should just simply get `doc_val` for given `doc_id` which has minimum `doc_val.val`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doc_val` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `doc_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `val` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `criteria` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('3', '1', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('4', '4', 'The earth is like a ball.');

INSERT INTO `doc_val` (`id`, `doc_id`, `val`, `type`, `criteria`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 100, 'D', 'L'),
  ('2', '1', 101, 'D', 'L'),
  ('3', '1', 80, 'H', 'L'),
  ('4', '2', 10, 'H', 'S'),
  ('5', '2', 90, 'H', 'L'),
  ('6', '3', 100, 'D', 'L'),
  ('7', '3', 100, 'D', 'L');
```

With this query if I take `b.type = 'D'` simply as part of where condition, I loose all docs which do not have type as D.

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content, b.val, b.type, b.criteria
FROM `docs` a
  JOIN `doc_val` b ON b.doc_id = a.id
  WHERE a.`rev` = 1 and b.type = 'D' and b.criteria = 'L'      
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
HAVING min(b.`val`)
```

[image]

If we do not consider `type=D` as condition at all, the output for this condition kind of worked but,

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content, b.val, b.type, b.criteria
FROM `docs` a
  JOIN `doc_val` b ON b.doc_id = a.id
  WHERE a.`rev` = 1 and b.criteria = 'L'      
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
HAVING min(b.`val`)
```

**final expected output:**

[image]

But Technically without `type=D` as condition, I should have received an output for `doc.id = 1` as:

[image]

1. So I am probably doing something wrong with use of `HAVING` any direction would be helpful.
2. Is it possible to prioritize `doc_val.type` with `doc_val.type = D`, such that when a row with `type = D` it takes priority, if it doesn't exist simply take one with minimum value without considering `type`?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I'm still with the old question... I also get the same result when removing `type='D'` condition but I didn't think that's an answer. There are a few ways I found but all of them is not certain.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar expected output is https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVH8R.png (also in question)

Comment: Learn to use a proper `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also, what's the use of `GROUP BY` without any aggregation?

Comment: @Eric you're right, while trying to find a solution I sure did do lot of stupid stuff. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98612b5f8674826d77313238f3545242)**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.id, a.rev, a.content, MIN(b.val) val, b.type, b.criteria
    FROM
        `docs` a
    JOIN `doc_val` b ON b.doc_id = a.id
    WHERE
        a.`rev` = 1 AND b.criteria = 'L'
    GROUP BY a.id , a.rev , a.content , b.type , b.criteria) A
WHERE
    val IN (SELECT 
            MAX(val)
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                a.id, a.rev, a.content, MIN(b.val) val, b.type, b.criteria
            FROM
                `docs` a
            JOIN `doc_val` b ON b.doc_id = a.id
            WHERE
                a.`rev` = 1 AND b.criteria = 'L'
            GROUP BY a.id , a.rev , a.content , b.type , b.criteria) B
        WHERE
            A.content = B.content)
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  rev content                                            val   type  criteria                  
1   1   The earth is flat                                   100  D     L
2   1   One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin   90   H     L
3   1   The earth is flat and rests on a bull's horn        100  D     L
```

Comment: So I tried this scenario: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0d6a508a7654e6bd4efb7e9d1b496de  Where I modified first 3 doc_val to have different values, It failed on this scenario.

Comment: As much as this returns the correct output, I couldn't wrap my head around it. @roko condition where `type='D'` is a priority and if `type='D'` doesn't exist, any type with the smallest value will do wasn't included in the query.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple tests, I've come up with something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content, c.val, c.type, c.criteria
FROM `docs` a
  JOIN 
  (SELECT doc_id,criteria,
       LEFT(gctv,1) AS 'Type',
       SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(gctv,',',' '),' ',1),2) AS 'val' 
  FROM
    (SELECT doc_id,criteria,
            CASE 
            WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(MID(ctv,INSTR(ctv,@type)) ,' ','')
            WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type)=0 THEN REPLACE(ctv,' ','') END AS gctv 
     FROM          
        (SELECT doc_id ,criteria,
                GROUP_CONCAT(tv ORDER BY val ASC) AS ctv 
          FROM
             (SELECT doc_id,criteria,val,
                     CONCAT_WS(' ',TYPE,VAL) tv
                FROM doc_val
                     WHERE criteria='L'
              )A
           GROUP BY doc_id
          )B, (SELECT @type:='D') temp
      )C) c
    ON a.id=c.doc_id
    WHERE rev=1;
```

I try to break it down:

This is the core of the query,

```
SELECT doc_id,criteria,val,
       CONCAT_WS(' ',TYPE,VAL) tv
            FROM doc_val
                WHERE criteria='L';
```

Basically, what its doing here is to combine `Type` and `val` into one column, with the condition of `criteria='L'`. The results look like this:

[image: result1]

The first outer query,

```
SELECT doc_id, criteria,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tv ORDER BY val ASC) AS ctv 
  FROM
      (SELECT doc_id,criteria,val,
              CONCAT_WS(' ',TYPE,VAL) tv
       FROM doc_val
          WHERE criteria='L'
       )A
  GROUP BY doc_id
```

is performing a `GROUP_CONCAT` based on the core query result and its grouped by `doc_id`. Which produces a result like below:

[image: result2]

You notice in the `GROUP_CONCAT` I've added a condition to `ORDER BY val ASC`. This will return the smallest value first from left to right order.

Then we go to the third query:

```
SELECT doc_id,criteria,
        CASE 
        WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(MID(ctv,INSTR(ctv,@type)) ,' ','')
        WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type)=0 THEN REPLACE(ctv,' ','') END AS gctv 
 FROM          
    (SELECT doc_id ,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tv ORDER BY val ASC) AS ctv 
      FROM
         (SELECT doc_id,val,
                 CONCAT_WS(' ',TYPE,VAL) tv
            FROM doc_val
                 WHERE criteria='L'
          )A
       GROUP BY doc_id
      )B, (SELECT @type:='D') temp
```

This is where the type condition is used and instead of typing one by one (which what I've done earlier), I use a variable so if the type condition is no longer 'D', you only need to change it from the variable. You will see more operators is used here.

`INSTR` is to find whether in the 'ctv' column has the `@type` variable which was set to 'D' or not. This will return the starting position of 'D'. For example, in the second image, the first result is `[H 80,D 100,D 101]` so the operator `INSTR` will look-up the position of first 'D' occurrence which will return `6` (counting from left to right including spaces and comma). The second return `0` because it did not find any `D` inside the column. `CASE WHEN` will check if the value=0 then it will return the value in the column as is, if the value <> 0, it will return value based on the position extracted from `INSTR(ctv,@type)`. That is why I've added another operator to get the column value from the position (`MID` ). I've included `REPLACE` to remove the spaces in between type and val. To understand the query more, I have prepared a query breakdown of the operation below:

```
SELECT doc_id,criteria,
       INSTR(ctv,@type),
       MID(ctv,INSTR(ctv,@type)),
       REPLACE(MID(ctv,INSTR(ctv,@type)) ,' ',''),
       CASE 
           WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type) <> 0 
           THEN REPLACE(MID(ctv,INSTR(ctv,@type)) ,' ','')
           WHEN INSTR(ctv,@type)=0 
           THEN REPLACE(ctv,' ','') 
       END AS gctv,
       SUBSTRING(REPLACE(ctv,' ',''),1)
 FROM          
    (SELECT doc_id,criteria,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tv ORDER BY val ASC) AS ctv 
      FROM
         (SELECT doc_id,criteria,val,
                 CONCAT_WS(' ',TYPE,VAL) tv
            FROM doc_val
                 WHERE criteria='L'
          )A
       GROUP BY doc_id
      )B, (SELECT @type:='D') temp
```

Query above will return the following:

[image: result3]

The last part here:

```
SELECT doc_id,
       LEFT(gctv,1) AS 'Type',
       SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(gctv,',',' '),' ',1),2) AS 'val'
```

the first operator of `REPLACE` is to change commas into spaces (refer `gctv` result in photo above). Then with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, it takes the first 'type+val' in the column then `SUBSTRING` will return value from position 2 - which was from taken from `val` column (this is assuming that your `type` column only consists of single character).

Fiddle here: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ya8STcWacGoQPf5rRnniR/0)

Comment: Thanks, this does solve it, however I'd wait for optimized answer if there's any before accepting the answer.

Comment: I agree. I'm also waiting for other suggestions. It's very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your desired outcome

See demo here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e32ec/32

```
Select *
from(
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.content, b.val, b.type, b.criteria
FROM `docs` a
  JOIN `doc_val` b ON b.doc_id = a.id
  WHERE a.`rev` = 1 and b.criteria = 'L'      
Order by `a`.`id`, FIELD(b.type, 'D','H','A'), b.`val` ) as sub
GROUP BY `id`
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  rev content                                            val   type  criteria                  
1   1   The earth is flat                                   100  D     L
2   1   One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin   90   H     L
3   1   The earth is flat and rests on a bull's horn        100  D     L
```

Comment: For the first row, with docs.id = 1, there is a row with type = D which needs to have priority even though value for the one with type = H is minimum.

Comment: edited the order by. Hope you have only these two types

Comment: Since there can be more than 2 types and in some cases, A could be a type, order by might not help. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4507d4/1

Comment: Edited: you can order by specific fields with order by FIELD(b.type, 'D','H','A')

Comment: Thanks but this still won't be possible since I have 900 different types, this was just a small scenario off of it.